# Which particles does the Higgs Field give mass to?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, standard-model, higgs, symmetry-breaking

I have found contradictory information about this. Does the Higgs field give mass only to the $W^+$, $W^-$, and $Z^0$ bosons or does it give mass to other particles as well?

Comment: And now there is contradictory information here on this answer, with at least two answerers disagreeing with the accepted answer as regards neutrinos.

Comment: The disagreement could probably have been reduced if your question title said **according to the Standard Model, which particles...**

Comment: Would you say this is professional disagreement on forefront research or a breakdown in consistency in the science?

Comment: Don’t assume that people who write answers on this site are necessarily professional physicists. Sometimes profiles will have this information. Neutrinos are a current research topic, and there are a variety of ideas about how to extend the Standard Model to explain their oscillations. I don’t think there is any breakdown in the consistency of the science.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Higgs field $\phi$ undergoes spontaneous symmetry breaking$^\dagger$ (from a complex doublet to a real scalar field, whose quantum is the Higgs boson) in a process named the Higgs mechanism. $^\dagger$: well it's a local/gauge symmetry, not global, so it's not "real" SSB, hence the different name "Higgs mechanism".

This has two consequences:

- the gauge bosons $W^\pm$ and $Z^0$ acquire a mass term, which they couldn’t have had a priori without breaking gauge invariance. The mass depends on the VEV (vacuum expectation value) of the Higgs field, but it doesn’t arise from a direct interaction term (see below) between the Higgs field and the gauge bosons. This new mass mode is the “would-be” Goldstone boson associated with the breaking of the Higgs field symmetry.
  (By “no direct interaction term” I mean that the term containing a product between the gauge boson and the Higgs field is hidden in the gauge covariant derivate $D^\mu$.)
- the fundamental fermions (quarks, leptons, but not neutrinos) also acquire a mass term. This arises from a direct interaction term between the fermionic field $\psi$ and the Higgs field, called the Yukawa Lagrangian sector. This looks like $ \mathcal{L}_Y \propto \Gamma \bar L \phi R, $ where $\Gamma$ is the Yukawa coupling to the specific fermionic field $\psi$, and $L$ and $R$ are the left- and right- handed components of $\psi$. Neutrinos have no right-handed partner so they cannot gain mass through a Yukawa coupling.

So the Higgs field is responsible for the masses of all the elementary particles (including the Higgs boson) short of neutrinos.

Comment: "Neutrinos have no right-handed partner so they cannot gain mass through a Yukawa coupling" is an oddly dated thing to say. They most likely do have a right-handed partner and a Higgs coupling just like all the other fermions. We shouldn't be asserting that they don't.

Comment: Within the current formulation of the Standard Model?

Comment: I think the current formulation of the standard model has right handed neutrinos and a Majorana term (whose coefficient may be zero). I don't think the standard model of twenty years ago should still be called standard when no one believes in it any more.

Comment: @benrg "oddly dated" Did I miss something, was the right-handed neutrino found? A reference would help.

Comment: @benrg "Standard Model" is its **name**, not its job description. Until a revision is generally accepted by the scientific community, it stays the same -- no neutrino masses. Yes, this contradicts observation. Yes, it means the Standard Model is somehow wrong. No, it doesn't mean the Standard Model suddenly changes its features in an inconsistent way.

Comment: @my2cts If experimental detection of all of the particles was a prerequisite to being called "standard", then it never would have been called "standard".

Comment: @RossPresser  Where does that idea come from? When the model was consistent with all data and was literally the standard model of particle physics, I doubt anybody planned that it would keep that name forever even after contradictory data came along. When they found accelerating Hubble expansion, they modified the standard cosmological model in the simplest way that fit. It may turn out to be wrong. It's the standard model, not the correct model.

Comment: You’re right. It *may* turn out to be wrong. Right-handed neutrino may turn out to be a thing. For now, they’re not.

Comment: @SuperCiocia What you take as the standard model in your answer *is definitely* wrong. The simplest extension that allows neutrino mass, which everyone in practice now takes as the standard against which other proposed models of neutrino mass are judged no matter what you call it, may or may not be wrong.

Comment: You're right. It may or or may not be wrong.

Comment: @SuperCiocia: Observing a right-handed neutrino reaction became theoretically possible as soon as they were found to have mass due to relativistic effects. (There exists a frame in which any given neutrino is right-handed...)

Comment: @benrg You seem so certain of the sterile neutrino, but for now it is a hypothesis outside the standard model.

Comment: I not forgot your explanation of the Lagrangian equation in chat :-)

Answer (score 11):

In the Standard Model, the Higgs field also gives mass to the six quarks (up, down, strange, charm, top, bottom) and the three charged leptons (electron, muon, tau) through [Yukawa couplings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism#Consequences_for_fermions). Some related mechanism may give neutrinos a small mass. (They’re massless in the Standard Model, but we know this is wrong.) Finally, one can argue that the Higgs field gives the Higgs boson its mass.

In short, every elementary particle except neutrinos gets its mass from the Higgs field. We’re not sure yet how neutrinos get theirs.

Comment: Almost certainly the neutrinos couple to the Higgs just like the other fermions. There's no reason they wouldn't. If there's a Majorana coupling, it's between the sterile neutrinos and antineutrinos, and they still have to couple to the weak charged neutrinos somehow.

Comment: Does this mean that the fermions enter the theory initially as massless particles?

Comment: @Kai Yes, that’s right.

Comment: @G.Smith why is that? I understand why the gauge bosons have to be massless but why do we need the fermions to also obtain their masses from the Higgs mechanism/Yukawa coupling?

Comment: @Kai The Wikipedia link explains that “mass terms preclude chiral gauge invariance”.

Comment: @G.Smith right but I still don't get why, I always learned that gauge field cannot have mass terms because they are not gauge invariant ( i.e. $m^2 A^\mu A_\mu$). But I've never heard that massive matter fields preclude gauge invariance... But perhaps I need to understand the operative word "chiral" in the context of gauge invariance.

Comment: @Kai This is probably elementary, but I don’t have a good explanation. I’m better at GR than I am at QFT, especially when chiral fermions are involved. Hopefully someone will explain it to both of us.

Answer (score 4):

The Higgs field is coupled to the fermions (quarks and charged leptons) in the standard model via Yukawa couplings. As a result of the Higgs mechanism, the Higgs field then gives mass to these fermions, in addition to the weak bosons.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The Higgs Field gives mass to :-

1. Everything marked in purple i.e. the quarks and anti-quarks
2. Everything marked in green i.e. leptons and anti-leptons, which includes electrons, positrons, tau-particles, neutrinos etc.
3. The yellow marked particle i.e. Higgs Boson, an excitation of the Higgs Field
4. The orange-red marked particles, except for 2 (photon [$\gamma$] and gluon [$g$])

Comment: Can you support your claim that the Higgs definitely gives neutrinos mass?

Comment: It seems from the other answers that its not proven but likely.

Comment: Well, I changed my answer because we really don’t know. And Yukawa couplings would need right-handed neutrinos, as SuperCiocia mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The Higgs field gives mass to all fermions and three weak gauge bosons (and itself) in the Standard Model. The masses of the fermions are proportional to their Yukawa couplings.

The Yukawa couplings of the neutrinos were long neglected due to their small size, and sometimes assumed to be zero. Although the evidence is consistent with nonzero neutrino Yukawa couplings, there are Standard-Model extensions where fermions also have Majorana masses. Such masses for the neutrinos have not yet been ruled out by experiment, which means we cannot be certain the neutrino Yukawa couplings are nonzero.