# Which particles do $W$ bosons interact with to gain mass?

Tags: mass, standard-model, higgs, bosons, electroweak

Which particles interact with  $W$ bosons to give them mass?
I am aware that Higgs particles alone are not responsible for the mass of other particles.
In non-mathematical terms which particles give the $W$ bosons mass?
Which particles make the largest contribution to the mass?

Comment: W bosons get their mass through interacting with just Higgs fields, much unlike hadrons.

Comment: As an electron passes through the Higgs field which particles give it mass?

Comment: "passing through the Higgs field" is frame dependent. The Higgs field is a Lorentz scalar, meaning, no matter how fast an electron is moving (which is meaningless in special relativity), the Higgs field looks the same. The electron-Higgs coupling just means at zero momentum, the electron still has energy $E=m_ec^2$.

Comment: Electrons and all charged leptons pick up their mass through interactions with the Higgs field (only; not quarks!).

Comment: @CosmasZachos what's the deal with quarks?

Comment: The deal is they *also* interact strongly with gluons and thereby get an "additional"  mass through them, to turn into constituent quarks, which are a hundred times heavier than the current quarks they started as (whose mass comes from Higgs field interactions, just like those of the leptons). So, light quarks, get the bulk of their effective mass from gluon interactions. SM books cover this well.

Comment: I understand the relativistic mass gain for quarks but when you say a particle interacts with the Higgs field are there force carrying bosons exchanged between Higgs field and the particle gaining mass or is there just a mathematical equation saying that the particle slows down? Can the Higgs interaction be visualised as Feynman diagrams?

Comment: Particle exchange in this context is wildly misguided, of course, but, yes, most good QFT books outline how the zero mode of the Higgs field curves the dispersion relation of the fermion; of course it's all in the math. If you get attached to a dufus popular science story you do your  mind a nasty disservice. [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/571121/which-particles-does-the-higgs-field-give-mass-to?rq=1).